# Why is `sed` no op much faster than `awk` in this case

Tags: awk, sed, performance

I am trying to understand some performance issues related to `sed` and `awk`, and I did the following experiment,

```
$ seq 100000 > test
$ yes 'NR==100001{print}' | head -n 5000 > test.awk
$ yes '100001{p;b}' | head -n 5000 > test.sed
$ time sed -nf test.sed test
real    0m3.436s
user    0m3.428s
sys     0m0.004s
$ time awk -F@ -f test.awk test
real    0m11.615s
user    0m11.582s
sys     0m0.007s
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

Here, since the test file only contains 100000 lines, all the commands in `test.sed` and `test.awk` are no-ops. Both programs only need to match the line number with the address (in `sed`) or `NR`(in `awk`) to decide that the command does not need to be executed, but there is still a huge difference in the time cost. Why is it the case? Are there anyone with different versions of `sed` and `awk` installed that gives a different result on this test?

**Edit**:
The results for `mawk` (as suggested by @mosvy), `original-awk`(the name for "one true awk" at debian based systems, suggested by @GregA.Woods) and `perl` are given below,

```
$ time mawk -F@ -f test.awk test
real    0m5.934s
user    0m5.919s
sys     0m0.004s
$ time original-awk -F@ -f test.awk test
real    0m8.132s
user    0m8.128s
sys     0m0.004s
$ yes 'print if $.==100001;' | head -n 5000 > test.pl
$ time perl -n test.pl test
real    0m33.245s
user    0m33.110s
sys     0m0.019s
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.4 20171017
$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Replacing `-F@` with `-F ''` does not make observable changes in the case of `gawk` and `mawk`. `original-awk` does not support empty `FS`.

**Edit 2**
The test by @mosvy gives different results, 21s for `sed` and 11s for `mawk`, see the comment below for details.

Comment: I also suggest you try it with `mawk` ;-)

Comment: Without any testing, I wonder if awk is doing more work per line because of the -F@ field splitting.

Comment: One should always test Awk performance and compatability against The One True Awk.  https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk

Comment: @JeffSchaller I try to figure out a way so that awk does not do any field splitting at all, but at least failed for `GNU awk`. Setting `FS` to empty string seems to cause `awk` to split each individual character as a field.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Updated.

Comment: @JigglyNaga ah yes - gotcha

Comment: on my (much slower) laptop `mawk` is almost twice as fast as `sed` (11s vs 21s), though it's not doing any extra optimizations either (it's still doing the `NR==100001` check 5k x 100k = 500M times). As to perl, it's expected to be so much slower, since perl is not using any kind of bytecode -- when running a script, perl is simply walking through `->op_next` pointers the syntax tree the parser had built ;-)

Comment: Interesting. I will include your result.

Comment: Now try replacing `yes` with `echo`, and get rid of the `| head -n 5000`, to create truly realistic tests and re-run all the different test cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`awk` has a wider feature set than `sed`, with a more flexible syntax.  So it's not unreasonable that it'll take longer both to parse its scripts, and to execute them.

As your example command (the part inside the braces) never runs, the time-sensitive part should be your test expression.

## awk

First, look at the test in the `awk` example:

```
NR==100001
```

and see the effects of that in `gprof` (GNU awk 4.0.1):

```
  %   cumulative   self                self     total
 time   seconds   seconds      calls   s/call   s/call  name
 55.89     19.73    19.73          1    19.73    35.04  interpret
  8.90     22.87     3.14  500000000     0.00     0.00  cmp_scalar
  8.64     25.92     3.05 1000305023     0.00     0.00  free_wstr
  8.61     28.96     3.04  500105014     0.00     0.00  mk_number
  6.09     31.11     2.15  500000001     0.00     0.00  cmp_nodes
  4.18     32.59     1.48  500200013     0.00     0.00  unref
  3.68     33.89     1.30  500000000     0.00     0.00  eval_condition
  2.21     34.67     0.78  500000000     0.00     0.00  update_NR
```

~50% of the time is spent in "interpret", the top-level loop to run the opcodes resulting from the parsed script.

Every time the test is run (ie. 5000 script lines * 100000 input lines), `awk` has to:

- Fetch the built-in variable "NR" (`update_NR`).
- Convert the string "100001" (`mk_number`).
- Compare them (`cmp_nodes`, `cmp_scalar`, `eval_condition`).
- Discard any temporary objects needed for the comparison (`free_wstr`, `unref`)

Other `awk` implementations won't have the exact same call flow, but they will still have to retrieve variables, automatically convert, then compare.

## sed

By comparison, in `sed`, the "test" is much more limited.  It can only be a single address, an address range, or nothing (when the command is the first thing on the line), and `sed` can tell from the first *character* whether it's an address or command.  In the example, it's

```
100001
```

...a single numerical address.  The profile (GNU sed 4.2.2) shows

```
  %   cumulative   self                self     total
 time   seconds   seconds      calls   s/call   s/call  name
 52.01      2.98     2.98     100000     0.00     0.00  execute_program
 44.16      5.51     2.53 1000000000     0.00     0.00  match_address_p
  3.84      5.73     0.22                               match_an_address_p
[...]
  0.00      5.73     0.00       5000     0.00     0.00  in_integer
```

Again, ~50% of the time is in the top-level `execute_program`.  In this case, it's called once per input line, then loops over the parsed commands.  The loop starts with an address check, but that's not all it does in your example (see later).

The line numbers in the input script were parsed at compile-time (`in_integer`). That only has to be done once for each address number in the input, ie. 5000 times, and doesn't make a significant contribution to the overall running time.

That means that the address check, `match_address_p`, only compares integers that are already available (through structs and pointers).

### further `sed` improvements

The profile shows that `match_address_p` is called 2*5000*100000 times, ie. *twice* per script-line*input-line.  This is because, behind the scenes, GNU `sed` treats the "start block" command

```
100001{...}
```

as a negated branch to the end of the block

```
100001!b end; ... :end
```

This address match *succeeds* on every input line, causing a branch to the end of the block (`}`).  That block-end has no associated address, so it's another successful match.  That explains why so much time is spent in `execute_program`.

So that `sed` expression would be even faster if it omitted the unused `;b`, and the resulting unnecessary `{...}`, leaving only `100001p`.

```
  %   cumulative   self               self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds     calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 71.43      1.40     1.40 500000000     0.00     0.00  match_address_p
 24.49      1.88     0.48    100000     0.00     0.00  execute_program
  4.08      1.96     0.08                             match_an_address_p
```

That halves the number of `match_address_p` calls, and also cuts most of the time spent in `execute_program` (because the address match never succeeds).

Comment: JiggilyNaga, what was the command to get the output like that, please?

Comment: @Tagwint I recompiled `awk` and `sed` with profiling enabled, then used `gprof` (part of binutils).  Though the large numbers meant I had to realign the columns manually.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above script is not a noop for awk:

Even if you do not use the contents of the fields, according to [GAWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html) for each record that is read in the following steps are inevitably performed:

- scanning for all occurrences of the FS
- field splitting
- updating th NF variable

If you are not using this information it just gets discarded afterwards.

If a field separator does not occur within the record, awk still has to assign text to $0 (and in your case to $1, too), and set NF to the actual number of obtained fields (1 in the sample above)

Comment: all that doesn't really make a difference -- try `time gawk '$1=$1+$1' test >/dev/null`; it's really the big unrealistic script that's blowing it up. Also notice that (at least the original awk) does not do splitting until the `$1`, ... fields are first used.